# C++ Char array conversion to Hex or char array

Tags: c++

I would appreciate for some C++ expertize advice on this please. I have a Char array

```
     <unsigned char ch1[100];>
```

data (ASCII code) gets filled in this ( max 6 or 8 array spaces and rest is empty). I want to process valid bits in the array only either converting them to  Hex or again Char array. I tried

```
     <memcpy (ch1,ch2,sizeof(ch1))>
```

but all garbage values are also copied..... :(

```
       <strcpy gives me an error>
```

also number of bytes copied are dynamic ( 1 time :- 4; 2 time :- 6.....)

Comment: Please elaborate on "valid bits".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know how many valid bytes do you have in your array? If yes, you can pass that number in as the 3rd argument of memcpy.

Otherwise you can zero-initialize the array and use strcpy which will stop on the first zero:

```
char ch1[100];
// zero out the array so we'll know where to stop copying
memset(ch1, 0, sizeof(ch1));

... data gets filled here ....

strcpy (ch2, ch1);
// zero out array again so we'll catch the next characters that come in
memset(ch1, 0, sizeof(ch1));

... life goes on ...
```

Comment: number of bytes copied are dynamic keep changing :(

Comment: I would make ch1 101 bytes then to make sure you always have a '\0' terminator. You also assume the input does not include a '\0' character.

Comment: so use the above code. zero-initialize the array, read with strcpy, then zero it out again.

Comment: @Martin York: 100 is fine for memset, and I gather he only expects 6-8 characters to come in. But I don't have a great feeling about the project in general. :)

Answer (score 0):

So only copy the chars that are actually initialized. *You* as a programmer are responsible for tracking what's initialized and what's not.